# harmon.ie keeps installing version 6.8.1.3788 although latest installer downloaded

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-outlook-2016

as mentioned above, I can't get the new version 7 onto my PC (Win10 1709; Outlook 2016) I downloaded latest installer but but I get only Version as mentioned installed instead of latest version 7.
Installed, uninstalled, rebooted several times already. even deleted the \Mainsoft-registry folder.

Answer (score 0):

1.Check if the client meets the requirement.

[enter link description here](https://harmon.ie/documentation/sharepoint/outlook/welcome)

2.Install the add-in in a new fresh Outlook client, check the result.
3.Ask the add-in vendor for support.